# What is the proper way to create entities in data access layer in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, n-tier-architecture

I have a sample ASP.net application, and I want to create it using n tier architecture, so I have a data base that contains tables and stored procedures (that perform (CRUD) operations on these tables)
, now when I tried to create the data access layer I created methods that uses ado.net to call these stored procedures,and I have created it but these methods returns datatables like this one:

```cs
public DataTable getallcourcesdetailsbyid(string courseid) {
    SqlParameter[] parameter = new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@courseid", courseid) };

    return sqlhelper.ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand("usp_getcoursedetailsbyid", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameter);
}
```

So I found that there is better way to create classes with properties that represents tables in the database to hold the data returned by data access layer
like this one:

```cs
 class course{
    public int courseid { get; set; }
    public string coursename { get; set; }
    public short specializationid { get; set; }
    public short subjectid { get; set; }
    public short instructorid { get; set; }
    public string startdate { get; set; }
    public string enddate { get; set; }
    public bool isactive { get; set; }
    public bool isdeleted { get; set; }
}
```

But these stored procedures not always returns the data from specific table for example the class course above present the course table in the data base but the method above called "getallcourcesdetailsbyid" call stored procedure with the following code

```sql
select courseid,coursename,startdate,enddate,courseimgpath,specialization,firstname,lastname,subjectname,price,coursedetails,teacherimgpath 
from joacademytest.course  
inner join joacademytest.specialization ON joacademytest.course.specializationid = joacademytest.specialization.specializationid 
inner join joacademytest.[subject]  on joacademytest.course.subjectnameid=joacademytest.[subject].subjectid
inner join joacademytest.teachers on joacademytest.course.instructerid=joacademytest.teachers.teacherid
inner join dbo.courcesprices on joacademytest.course.priceid=dbo.courcesprices.priceid
 where joacademytest.course.isactive=1 and joacademytest.course.isdeleted=0 and courseid = @courseid;
```

So the stored procedure will not return the same column exists in the course object but it represent columns from 4 joined tables, so do I have to create the entity classes based on the columns existing on the tables or based on the columns returned by my stored procedure. I have searched the Internet and never found any body mentioned that I can create entity classes based on stored procedure returned column which made me confused.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with creating classes that map to the results of a store procedure. Infact Many of the ORMs like entity framework, nHibernate allow you to do that. In the end It all depends on what you want to achieve, performance, maintenance etc and these are very broad topics. to answer your question and keeping in mind your current setup, i would propose -

- Create Entity that map to store procs if, store procs are the preferred way of getting data from database, Infact so that you dont re-invent the wheel you can use one of the many Orm tools - [dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper), [EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx).
- Or instead of creating entities from your datatables , you can return dynamic objects.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is I create a classes that represents my tables in my database. In a scenario like you describe, where you have a stored procedure that returns data, I move it to a view. Then I create a class that represents that view. If you can't do that and you must keep it in a stored procedure, then I would just create a class around what the stored procedure returns.